# Selenium explicit wait doesnt work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a code that tell Selenium to wait until an element is clickable but for some reason, Selenium doesnt wait but instead, click that element and raise a Not clickable at point (x, y) immediately. Any idea how to fix this ?

```
x = '//*[@id="arrow-r"]/i'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://www.inc.com/inc5000/list/2017')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, x)))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(x).click()
```

Comment: What is EC class ?

Comment: @cezarypiatek Expected conditions

Comment: EC.element_to_be_clickable check if element is visible and enabled. In terms of visibility it doesn't cover scenario when element is behind other. Maybe your page use something like blockUI widget and click() occurs before the cover disappears.

Comment: @cezarypiatek So should i put that wait until the Popup ad disappear then click the element?

Comment: Yes, definitely. There is a dedicated EC method which check if element is not visible. You should add this check against popup element.

Comment: This is a common issue right now with the recent updates of Chrome. Make sure Chrome and Chrome driver are up to date and try it again.

Comment: @JeffC I downloaded the latest Chromedriver but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 1):

EC.element_to_be_clickable check if element is visible and enabled. In terms of visibility it doesn't cover scenario when element is behind other. Maybe your page use something like blockUI widget and click() occurs before the cover disappears. You can check if element is truly clickable by enriching EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, x)) check with assertion that ensure element is not behind by other. In my projects I use implementation as below:

```
static bool IsElementClickable(this RemoteWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    return (bool)driver.ExecuteScript(@"
            (function(element){
                var rec = element.getBoundingClientRect();
                var elementAtPosition = document.elementFromPoint(rec.left+rec.width/2, rec.top+rec.height/2);
                return element == elementAtPosition || element.contains(elementAtPosition);
            })(arguments[0]);
    ", element);
}
```

This code is in C# but I'm sure you can easily translate into your programming language of choice.

UPDATE:
I wrote a blog post about problems related to clicking with selenium framework https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-click-with-selenium-so-hard/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the 'waiting' section for the Python Selenium docs: [Click here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Wait will be like:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of((By.XPATH, "Your xpath"))
)
element.click();
```

Comment: can you share link which you open for your project?

Comment: Try this XPath //div[@id='arrow-r']/i and increse time 30

Comment: its not good way but try this time.sleep(20) and if its not work then I guess pagination not show on the screen then you can go down of the page by using driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

Comment: time.sleep(20) worked but i cant use it for pagination because after clicking the next button, somehow the html content in the driver wouldnt change with it.

Comment: i dont thing that sleep can interact with you page html body

Comment: [This](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4801) could be a reason. Try updating the chromedriver to the latest version.

Comment: Good point you can download driver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads